# How to create High Quality Icons in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, bitmap, icons, system.drawing

I need to create high quality icons for my current project in vb.net

This is my code so far,

```
 Private Sub CreateIcon(ByVal bitmapName As String)
    Try
        Dim fi As New System.IO.FileInfo(bitmapName)
        Dim bmp As New Bitmap(fi.FullName)
        Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = System.IO.File.CreateText(fi.FullName.Replace(fi.Extension, ".ico"))
        Icon.FromHandle(bmp.GetHicon).Save(sw.BaseStream)
        sw.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex)
    End Try
End Sub
```

But the problem is it only gives me a very low quality icon at the end. Does anyone have any ideas for how to make a higher quality image?

Comment: to fix some possible memory leaks, check my answer...

Comment: Quality is subjective. What's wrong with the icons?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you should dig deeper into `ico` file format and see how to construct it manually. If your task is tend to support only specific cases (source size and format), you may investigate this project: [Dynamically Generating Icons (safely)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7122/Dynamically-Generating-Icons-safely).

The solvation has limitations, but it can be extended to match your requirements.